How do I modify the default skins in minecraft?
From what I know, your skins are stored in a specific folder/file that is often located in the Minecraft folder. I can't find a way to change the default skin.
The current version that I am running is 1.20.4 with Optifine. I'm having troubles trying to figure out how to get rid of the default skin.

To change the default skins, create a resource pack with the following asset files, depending on the player type you would like to replace:

assets\minecraft\textures\entity\steve.png
assets\minecraft\textures\entity\alex.png

Add a steve.png for any Steve (4-pixel arm) character, and add an alex.png for any Alex (3-pixel arm) character.

Note that becauce you're replacing the default character skin,

all skins for players you were unable to download a skin for will use that skin, which includes:

other cracked players
other players that join your internet-disconnected server (in offline mode)




Don't forget the players who plays with no skin

@Dave Don't they become Steve/Alex instead of whatever is in the datapack (as reported by the skin server; depending on the UUID of the account)?

I thought if the player uses no skin they default to what's in the data pack
